Spring Boot configuration value with .no. or .NO. not populating
I have a very simple Spring Boot app with country specific configuration properties, all known and easy stuff, nothing special.
It should work in 4 countries DK,SE,FI and NO. Injecting these properties using @Value

FX @Value("${app.nds.no.count}"),@Value("${app.nds.se.count}"),@Value("${app.nds.fi.count}") and @Value("${app.nds.dk.count}")
All work good except the one with .no. or .NO., it return an error

Could not resolve placeholder 'app.nds.no.count' in value "
${app.nds.no.count}"

I made sure the YML file is correct, and if i changed the .no. key to any other key it will work correctly.
How can keep the structure of the keys unchanged, and make .no. work ?

You encountered the YAML Norway problem.

Based on @Chin Huang comment and @vik answer.
The reason to why this is problematic, is “The Norway Problem” YAML has: when you abbreviate Norway to its ISO 3166-1 ALPHA-2 form NO, YAML will return false when parsing it:
countries:
- DK
- SE
- FI
- NO

    values
    {'countries': ['DK', 'SE', 'FI', False]}

The solution is to escape the  .no. or .NO. in single quotes.


Yes/yes and No/no converted to true and false accordingly, that's why we're not able to read mentioned properties.
FYI I'm using below config
app:
  nds:
    no:
      count: 10


